# elmah - not sending email in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application and I would like to implement sending exceptions to my email including all necessary information (referer, etc.). I do not want to store exceptions in database or files. Last project I used elmah and it worked like a charm.

In current project I face to one problem. I installed and configured elmah and on localhost (IIS Express 10.0; .NET Framework 4.0; ASP.NET: 4.6) it works pretty good. All exceptions are sent to my email. So mail connection credentials in web.config are OK.

But on production server (IIS 8.5; .NET Framework: 4.0; ASP.NET: 4.7) elmah sends nothing when exception occurs and I have no idea why. Is there any chance to get to know why?

I tested mail connection from production server to mail server by telnet and mail server is reachable.

So:
1. web.config should be OK - emails are sent on localhost
2. telnet connection to mailserver is reachable - so no firewall issue, etc.

What else can I do? How to debug elmah?

Comment: Check if your web.config transforme to the production is changing the credintials of the SMTP or if it's deleting them. It might be the problem.

Comment: web.config files on localhost and on production server are the same without any changes

Comment: Can you publish your web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours of debugging it turned out that external mail server was configured to reject sending email from specific user from specific IP.